# Subview that expands with window using NSAutolayout

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to learn auto layout so I can set up a moderately complicated display the way I want.  I'm starting with a simple version. At least I thought it was simple.

I have a content view containing a NSScrollView, and a zoom slider.  The scroll view is, of course, just a window into a larger 'canvas' on which the user can do things.

I'd like the scroll view to be as big as the window allows, with the slider underneath.

I've tried many things none of which work, in some cases when I resize the window smaller, the scroll view goes on up over the window's top bar, obscuring the title and the red yellow, green, dots.. this is just a grumble, I won't attempt to describe how I got it.

I'm working with Visual Format Language.

The immediate problem: I can only get the thing to work at all if I put in a hard size constraint on the scroll view.

I've got constraints like @"V:|[ScrollView]-[ZoomSlider(==35)]-| and 
@"|-20@1000-[ScrollView]-|"

With these, nothing shows at all, until I put a hard size on the scroll view:

For example, @"V:[ScrollView(>=70@20)]" and @"[ScrollView(>=140@20)]" results in a little tiny scroll view (as expected) just above the slider.

Window is resizable, all right.

Is there a simple way to make the scroll view resize to occupy the most space possible when I resize the window?  The only way I can think of off hand is to produce metrics for the scroll view based on window size, and use a notification to change the constraints when the window size changes.  There  should be something simpler!

THanks.ee

Answer (score 0):

OOps. Thought I knew the answer until I started to write it.

AT least here is a partial explanation of things that were causing me problems.

You can't add constraints that position or size the Window's content view. But apparently you can mess them up by deleting them programatically. Some of my problems were solved by getting rid of

```
[self.myContentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

and

```
    [self.myContentView removeConstraints:self.myContentView.constraints];
```

This left me with a lot of conflicting constraints. I fixed this be eliminating all content window constraints that I could in IB, then by marking the rest as placeholders.

I've got a ways to go before I understand how to use auto layout, but doing it in code is easier (for me) than doing it with IB